# Random variable X has the following discrete distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Random variable $X$ has the following discrete distribution:

$f(x) = k/x$    for $x = 1, 2, 3$

$f(x) = 0$      otherwise

1. Find $k$ so that $f(x)$ is a legitimate probability mass function
2. What is $E(X)$, the expected value of X?
3. Calculate $V(X)$, the variance of $X$.
4. Let $X_1$, $X_2$, ..., $X_{36}$ be a random sample selected from the distribution of X. Use the central limit theorem to approximate the probability that the sample mean is greater than 2.1 but less than 2.5.

Comment: this quetion is pretty bog standard first exercise on mass functions. it is even discrete. what have you tried?

Comment: To to make it clear: I am going to downvote anyone who just gives you the answer rather than hints.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1) What is the definition of a probability mass function?  What has to be true if order for the given $f$ to satisfy the definition?

2) What is the definition of the expected value of a discrete random variable?
What do you get (after answering (1)) when you plug in the given $f$?

3) Similar to (2)

4) The answers to (2) and (3) give you all the information about $X$ that you need for this.

Comment: For the first part, I know I have to have f(x) = 1, I'm just not sure how to get there without guessing and checking.

Comment: ^ no that is wrong. the mass SUMS to 1.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant. I'm not sure how to solve for that.

Comment: So what is the sum in terms of $k$?

Comment: I don't know, that's what I'm asking.

Comment: What's $f(1)$?  What's ...?  What is their sum?